# VIM with Syntastic: Why is VIM's JAVA syntax highlighting thrown off by `<` and `>` in a comment block?

Tags: vim, comments, syntastic

In VIM, when editing `.java` files, I'm seeing the syntax highlighter being thrown off by the `<` and `>` characters inside of comment blocks.

It seems to expect me to close the `<`characters with a `>`.

Here's an example:

```
/**
 *  `<` <-- this character causes a syntax error
 */
```

Using VIM with [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic).

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javadoc comments use html for formatting. `<` is the start of a tag and it never ends so it is invalid html. You need to use `&lt;` instead.

Comment: or alternatively, use `/*` instead of `/**` if you're not writing JavaDoc